# How to add to a list in C# via button/textbox in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, list

How to add to a list in C# via button/textbox in a windows form. I'm trying to add to my block sites list but does not seem to work , here are the two snippets below

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> BlockList = new List<string>();
    BlockList.Add("http://www.google.com");
    BlockList.Add("http://www.google.co.uk");
    BlockList.Add("http://www.bing.com");
    string[] BlockArray = BlockList.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < BlockArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (e.Url.Equals(BlockList[i]))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "NO NO NO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BlockList.Add(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: and what isn't working here?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET the add function gives a null error and does not add to list upon click

Comment: Your `BlockList` variable DNE outside `webBrowser1_Navigating` as it was created there.

Comment: It's not often you need to look up a duplicate for a C# scoping problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the BlockList as a member in the form class, not as a local variable inside a function. Then you will be able to use int i both functions.

Just add this member to the form class:

```
private List<string> BlockList = new List<string>() { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.bing.com" };
```

and change the webBrowser1_Navigating method to:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    string[] BlockArray = BlockList.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < BlockArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (e.Url.Equals(BlockList[i]))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "NO NO NO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message
        }
    }
}
```

You can also simplify the webBrowser1_Navigating method by replacing the loop over the BlockList list with the Contains method:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (BlockList.Contains(e.Url.ToString()))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "NO NO NO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! But it adds it to list as I'm running the Winform. However, when I run the app again it forgets it.

Comment: The BlockList variable is not persisted so you need to store it in a database or config file.

Comment: So, which would be better? Could you please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable BlockList must be global.

You have only a local declaration like this

```
   List<string> BlockList = new List<string>();
```

in your function "webBrowser1_Navigating"

Comment: if I place it in the constructor it gives an error in "webBrowser1_Navigating" on BlockList

Comment: You can add it as field or property to the class in which these two methods are present. Then you can initialize it in the same class constructor.